# Fundamental group of punctured strict henselization of a relative affine line over a non-regular base

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $R$ be a local ring with maximal ideal $m$ of residue characteristic $p\ge 0$. Let $A$ be the strict henselization of $R[t]$ at the ideal $(m,t)$.

What is the maximal prime-to-$p$ quotient of the étale fundamental group of $\operatorname{Spec} A[t^{-1}]$? Is this just the maximal prime-to-$p$ quotient of $\widehat{\mathbb{Z}}$?

The case where $R$ is regular follows from Abhyankar's lemma. Presumably non-regularity doesn't change much?